# how to add image to the html log in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

how to add image to the html log in robot framework? I want to add some picture into the html log in Robot Framework. Could any one have some ideas about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keyword `Log` from the BuiltIn library has `html` argument which can possibly do what you need. See doc: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it later

Answer (score 1):

Keyword is as follows.

```
Log            <img src="example.png">        html=true
```

Assuming the example.png file is in the same folder as the logs.