# Robot Framework add image to report

Tags: robotframework

I have a picture saved in folder (C:\temp)

How to add/embed this image to Robot Framework report?

Using Log and give path to file?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872620/how-to-add-image-to-the-html-log-in-robot-framework) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you! it worked: Log <img src="C:\\temp\\pic1.png">, html=yes

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid "broken image links", for example when moving the report from one machine to another, optimal way would be to output  tag as mentioned during the execution but encode the image file into base64 string and embed that string as src attribute of the img tag.

Comment: This sounds good: "encode the image file into base64 string and embed that string as src attribute of the img tag."
How to do it?